# Query by User Role type

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to formulate a way to query by a user role type in wordpress and have been using the following code which I found on Stack Overflow but it isn't working for me:

```
        <?php
            $friends = get_users( array( 'role' => 'mns' ) );
        $friend_ids = array();

            foreach( $friends as $friend ) 
                $friend_ids[] = $friend->ID;

            $news = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => implode( ',', $friend_ids ), 'post_type' => 'roleplays', ) );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $news->have_posts() ) : while ( $news->have_posts() ) : $news->the_post(); ?> 
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

The loop collects all the posts in the custom post type, but doesn't show only posts from the specific role type.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Do you included "wp_reset_postdata();"? When using the_post(), wp_reset_postdata() should be use to ensure that you don't get unexpected outcome. Outside that, I don't see what is causing the problem. Is there other custom php codes or plugins that may be interfering?

Comment: I do use the reset, yes.  Sorry, that should've been included.